# xUnit Parallel Test Collections

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I would like to have the ability to run test collections in parallel.

Here is what I have:

```
[Collection("Serial_01 Non-Parallel Collection")]
[CollectionDefinition("Serial_01 Non-Parallel Collection", DisableParallelization = true)]
public class SerialTest01
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task SerialTest01_Test01()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Assert.True(true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SerialTest01_Test02()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}

[Collection("Serial_02 Non-Parallel Collection")]
[CollectionDefinition("Serial_02 Non-Parallel Collection", DisableParallelization = true)]
public class SerialTest02
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task SerialTest02_Test01()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Assert.True(true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SerialTest02_Test02()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

From my understanding, when I defined the two collections I expected, when looking at the test explorer in visual studio, seeing the two collection running in parallel.

However I see them running one after the other.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't run them in parallel if you use Collection Fixtures. https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#collection-fixture

Comment: `DisableParallelization = true` means to **turn off** paralleization. Of course they run sequentially (barring other concerns). Also see [Running tests in parallel](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html). Also you are misusing `CollectionDefinition`. It should be defined on a single, **seperate** class. The name is then what you pass to `Collection`. However it's used for Collection Fixtures which you don't appear to be using. See stefan's link